# add ssh public key to azure devops through command line

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to add ssh public key to azure devops through command line?

The only way I found is to add it through UI ops: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#step-2-add-the-public-key-to-azure-devops